# How do I include an already existing web3 directory in a new directory without reuploading it

Tags: ipfs, web3storage

I have a folder that is already uploaded to w3storage. I want to include that folder in a new directory, but I dont want to upload the folder again. How do I do that in the JS client? Whats the w3 version of a folder link?

If there is an inbuilt solution, I cant find it. One might be able to make this feature on their own by changing the CAR file before its sent to the server, but CAR files confuse me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In principle, if the folder is pinned to IPFS and has a CID, there is not really any way to modify it. IPFS is immutable and the CID is cryptographically determined by the contents of the folder/file, so changing that content would also change the CID. IPNS served as a way to have more like a DNS solution where a static CID can point to different CIDs and change that pointer as well, but its not the best solution.

Comment: I'm not talking about editing a folder. I'm talking about creating a new folder that has a subfolder which already exists in w3storage.